# Hpa not fetching existing custom metric?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, prometheus, autoscaling

I'm using `mongodb-exporter` for store/query the metrics via `prometheus`. I have set up a custom metric server and storing values for that .

That is the evidence of `prometheus-exporter` and `custom-metric-server` works compatible .

**Query:**

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/monitoring/pods/*/mongodb_mongod_wiredtiger_cache_bytes"
```

**Result:**

```
{"kind":"MetricValueList","apiVersion":"custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/monitoring/pods/%2A/mongodb_mongod_wiredtiger_cache_bytes"},"items":[{"describedObject":{"kind":"Pod","namespace":"monitoring","name":"mongo-exporter-2-prometheus-mongodb-exporter-68f95fd65d-dvptr","apiVersion":"/v1"},"metricName":"mongodb_mongod_wiredtiger_cache_bytes","timestamp":"TTTTT","value":"0"}]}
```

In my case when I create a hpa for this custom metrics from mongo exporter, hpa return this error to me :

```
failed to get mongodb_mongod_wiredtiger_cache_bytes utilization: unable to get metrics for resource mongodb_mongod_wiredtiger_cache_bytes: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
```

What is the main issue on my case ? I have checked all configs and flow is looking fine, but where is the my mistake .

Help

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide your Deployment YAML?

Comment: deployment yaml for application or another compoents related with prometheus or metric server ?

Comment: YAMLS of: 1. mongodb-exporter, 2. prometheus-exporter, 3. HPA.
Did you create this all using some tutorials? Could you provide steps you did to deploy everything.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS I have handled issue via enabled the external metrics api server

Comment: If you found solution, please write what you did as an answer and accept it. It will be more visible for people who might have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you wrote that you have enabled `external.metrics`, however in original question you had issues with `custom.metrics`

In short:

- `metrics` supports only basic metric like CPU or Memory.
- `custom.metrics` allows you to extend basic metrics to all Kubernetes objects (http_requests, number of pods, etc.).
- `external.metrics` allows to gather metrics which are not Kubernetes objects:

> External metrics allow you to autoscale your cluster based on any
>   metric available in your monitoring system. Just provide a metric
>   block with a name and selector, as above, and use the External metric
>   type instead of Object

For more detailed description, please check [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-metrics-not-related-to-kubernetes-objects).

**Minikube**

To verify if `custom.metrics` are enabled you need to execute command below and check if you can see any `metrics-server...` pod.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
...
metrics-server-587f876775-9qrtc    1/1     Running   4          5d1h
```

Second way is to check if `minikube` have enabled `metrics-server` by

```
$ minikube addons list
...
- metrics-server: enabled
```

If it is disabled just execute

```
$ sudo minikube addons enable metrics-server
✅  metrics-server was successfully enabled
```

**GKE**

Currently at GKE `heapster` and `metrics-server` are turn on as default but `custom.metrics` are not supported by default.
You have to install `prometheus adapter` or `stackdriver`.

**Kubeadm**

Kubeadm do not include `heapster` or `metrics server` at the beginning. For easy installation, you can use [this YAML](https://github.com/luxas/kubeadm-workshop/blob/master/demos/monitoring/metrics-server.yaml).

Later you have to install `prometheus adapter`.

**Apply custom.metrics**

It's the same for `Minikube`, `Kubeadm`, `GKE`.

Easiest way to apply `custom.metrics` is to install [prometheus adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) via `Helm`.

After helm installation you will be able to see note:

```
NOTES:
my-release-prometheus-adapter has been deployed.
In a few minutes you should be able to list metrics using the following command(s):

  kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

As additional information, you can use `jq` to get more user friendly output.

`kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq .`