# Automatic scaling of pods or containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to scale either the number of containers in a pod or the number of pods (containing only 1 container)?

I want to have a setup where ideally 0 instances are running. Then whenever a user arrive at a page it should add another pod/container-instance, so that each user has their own environment. When the user leaves the specific environment should be terminated. Is this possible to set for any n-users. 
E.g. to have a limit of 5 users per pod/container. First person that joins means creating a new pod/container. The second just arrives at the same p/c and so on to the fifth. If a sixth user joins I want it to create a new pod/container for this user. A pod/container should be terminated if it has 0 connections.

I have read that if a container within a pod gets terminated - then all the containers of the same kind also gets terminated, which I want to avoid in case other users are connected to one of these containers.

Being fairly new within this docker / kubernetes stuff (using minikube as a test right now), I hope you can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look at how JupyterHub does this. What you basically want is a Service (with ideally more than 1 replica associated) that can spawn new `Pod`/`Service`/`Ingress` definitions.

Comment: Did you check information about HPA: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ with Prometheus: https://prometheus.io/ ? Your minikube is local or Cloud?

Comment: Currently it is local. The idea is that I test if my desired setup works locally with a single node and using minikube. Then if I get the desired result, I hope to scale it up in the cloud with multiple nodes.
Will definitely look into both of your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments you should check `Horizontal Pod Autoscaler` and `Cluster Autoscaler`.

[Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) can upscale or downscale number of your pods depends on metrics. If you want use `CPU` or `Memory` metrics, they are built-in in Kubernetes. Information how to use is well described in [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/).

When you will use `HPA` example from docs, please keep in mind, `HPA` need a few minutes to gather metrics and then display it.

If you would use other metrics (those like you mentioned in question) you should use `custom metrics` or `external metrics`, depends on your needs. To get those metrics you will need to deploy metrics agents who will gather this data. One of the most popular is [Prometheus adapter](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-adapter). I've already mentioned about this when use `kubeadm` or `minikube` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151513/hpa-not-fetching-existing-custom-metric).

If you want to autoscale nodes, you should read about [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler). As `CA` need to add/remove node at any time it's recommended to use Cloud environment.

For AWS you can check [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html) and if you would use GKE you should check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).